# How to add horizontal striped background to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
mydat <- data.frame(mean = c(23, 24, 15, 27, 18, 19, 23, 20, 32),
                    lower = c(20, 19, 13, 15, 14, 18, 20, 17, 20),
                    upper = c(25, 29, 17, 39, 22, 20, 26, 23, 40),
                    class = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                    domain = c("North", "North", "North", "West", "West", "West", "South", "South", "South"),
                    stripe = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1))
mydat$class <- as.factor(mydat$class)
mydat$domain <- as.factor(mydat$domain)
mydat$stripe <- as.factor(mydat$stripe)

mydat %>% ggplot(aes(x = mean, y = class, color = domain, Group = domain, xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + theme_few() + geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + xlab("Counts")
```

[image]

I would like to shade this plot with horizontal stripes. The desired output looks something like this:

[image]

I tried the following with `geom_rect` but I'm not sure what to put for `ymin` and `ymax` when my y-axis is a factor variable:

```
> mydat %>% ggplot(aes(x = mean, y = class, color = domain, Group = domain, xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
+   geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + theme_few() + geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + xlab("Counts") + geom_rect(aes(fill = stripe))
Error in `geom_rect()`:
! Problem while setting up geom.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `compute_geom_1()`:
! `geom_rect()` requires the following missing aesthetics: ymin and ymax
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

**EDIT** (using a range of 0  to 4 for the y-axis) Did not work out as intended.

```
mydat %>% ggplot(aes(x = mean, y = class, color = domain, Group = domain, xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + theme_few() + geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + xlab("Counts") + geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = 4, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, fill = stripe, colour = stripe, group = stripe))
```

[image]

Comment: Factors are generally integers starting at 1. So (0,4) would be a possible range that would encompass a three factor range.

Comment: @IRTFM I tried setting the range to (0, 4), but it looks the stripe is only showing up as a single color (please see updated post) and not according to the `stripe` variable I originally defined. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you needed was a rectangle for each y axis value, and more specific breaks. I'm sure there's a more elegant way to achieve the same result. This is kind of a hacky solution, but it works.

```
mydat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = mean, y = class, 
             xmin = lower, xmax = upper,
             Group = domain)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0.5, ymax = 1.5, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, 
                fill = stripe), alpha = 0.1) + 
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 2.5, ymax = 3.5, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, 
                fill = stripe), alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(color = domain), width = 0.1, 
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = domain), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "transparent")) +
  xlab("Counts") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]