Paint areas from a condition in ggplot2
This code is doing its job, but I want to paint the areas by the variable season ("Lean Season", "Not Lean Season"), and I don't know how to achieve that. I've tried with gem_area and geom_rect, but I am not succeeding, probably because the date is a date type.
I want to achieve what it seems in the picture attached with some alpha.
df <- read_csv("date,treatment,season,fcs
               2020-12-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,30.745913290689405
               2020-12-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,32.58976109215016
               2021-01-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,31.641855447680587
               2021-01-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,29.246535796766764
               2021-04-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,45.36691542288559
               2021-04-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,44.84256926952142
               2021-05-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,45.08060453400504
               2021-05-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,47.6203007518797
               2021-06-01,Comparison,Lean Season,42.512285012285005
               2021-06-01,Programme,Lean Season,39.663414634146356
               2021-07-01,Comparison,Lean Season,41.29671717171716
               2021-07-01,Programme,Lean Season,42.87848101265825
               2021-08-01,Comparison,Lean Season,49.14609571788413
               2021-08-01,Programme,Lean Season,46.7807881773399
               2021-09-01,Comparison,Lean Season,43.86548223350254
               2021-09-01,Programme,Lean Season,44.60335917312663
               2021-10-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,47.30050505050503
               2021-10-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,46.892768079800504
               2021-11-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,47.510126582278474
               2021-11-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,48.77791563275434
               2021-12-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,40.92144638403991
               2021-12-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,41.779556650246306
               2022-01-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,41.12373737373736
               2022-01-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,40.87468671679198
               2022-03-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,36.51898734177217
               2022-03-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,36.24120603015074
               2022-04-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,39.14631043256998
               2022-04-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,39.53708439897699
               2022-05-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,38.94874999999999
               2022-05-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,37.891857506361326
               2022-06-01,Comparison,Lean Season,37.82133676092546
               2022-06-01,Programme,Lean Season,37.12113402061855
               2022-07-01,Comparison,Lean Season,37.54615384615384
               2022-07-01,Programme,Lean Season,36.67179487179487
               2022-08-01,Comparison,Lean Season,38.99488491048593
               2022-08-01,Programme,Lean Season,37.49869109947643
               2022-09-01,Comparison,Lean Season,41.6801007556675
               2022-09-01,Programme,Lean Season,41.51658163265308
               2022-10-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,41.67602040816327
               2022-10-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,43.49354005167959
               2022-11-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,52.11023622047246
               2022-11-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,52.943243243243224
               2022-12-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,49.45025510204082
               2022-12-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,50.28481012658228
               2023-03-01,Comparison,Not Lean Season,19.80569251456746
               2023-03-01,Programme,Not Lean Season,20.968145869947254")

ggplot(df, aes(date, fcs, shape = treatment)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "solid", color = "black") +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = unique(df$date), labels = scales::date_format("%b %Y")) +
  labs(
    x = "",
    y = "Impact on Food Consumption Score",
    color = "",
    fill = "",
    shape = ""
  ) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 15) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"), # set panel background to white
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"), # set plot background to white (optional)
    legend.position = "bottom",
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)
  )



can geom_rect be the function you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74697396/striped-background-colour-on-every-other-x-block-in-ggplot2-in-r and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77342068/how-to-add-horizontal-striped-background-to-ggplot

Use a geom_rect() to create the background and set the xmin to date and xmax to the next value of date in the dataset using the lead() function from the dplyr package"
geom_rect(
    aes(
      xmin = date,
      xmax = dplyr::lead(date),
      ymin = -Inf,
      ymax = Inf,
      fill = season
    ),
    alpha = 0.2
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Not Lean Season" = "#0be232", "Lean Season" = "#0c8ae2"))

